# Hibernate multi-tenant naming strategy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, multi-tenant

I am building an application where multiple tenants have their own set of tables on a DB instance (same mysql database). I want the tables to be named like this: `tenantA_users, tenantA_orders`, `tenantB_users, tenantB_orders`.

I tried to implement something like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/naming-strategy-hibernate), but it seems like `Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();` is the [legacy way to bootstrap](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-bootstrap)

Is there a way to implement [Interface PhysicalNamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy.html) to be non-static so I can just append the `tenantName` string to the annotated `@Table` name provided in the class?

eg:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_order")
public class CustOrder {
```

I want the naming to be `tenantA_custom_order` `tenantB_custom_order`, not `tenantA_CustOrder`.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it using [MetadataBuilder applyPhysicalNamingStrategy(PhysicalNamingStrategy namingStrategy)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder.html#applyPhysicalNamingStrategy-org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy-)

This way I could send the tenantName string to the namingStragegy constructor.